# Jms consumer running in OutOfMemory

Tags: java, jms

We have an application that receives messages from the Broker and we use the Sun MessageQueue. We have approximately 4 message producers for a single Queue and a single consumer. The issue we are facing right now is that when the Queue is holding about 70,000 the receiver app crashes with an OutOfMemry. I know the issue is because the receiver is prefetching all the messages.

I tried setting the max amount of messages to a smaller number and activating Flow Control but that didnt work as there seemed to be a producer which did not respect at all that message limit and other producers would completely halt pausing the complete application. I know that limiting the amount of numbers is taken just as a suggestion but some producers would pause for half an hour and others would continue posting.

Is there a parameter that i could use to limit the Prefetching of that Queue or the complete broker?

EDIT:
Here is a piece of the code in charge of the consumer:

```
initializeQueue(){
    String queueName = ConfigManager.getString("changeRequest.messageQueue");
    String factoryName = ConfigManager.getString("changeRequest.factory");
    String initial = ConfigManager.getString("java.naming.factory.initial");
    String url = ConfigManager.getString("java.naming.provider.url");

    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, initial);
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);

    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);

    Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
    QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(factoryName);
    ctx.close();

    connection = factory.createQueueConnection();
    session = connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    receiver = session.createReceiver(queue);
}

    ------------
run(){
    while (true)
    {
      // receive some messages from the JMS Queue
      try
      {
        session.getTransacted();//access the session to make sure it is still alive
        if (timeout == NO_TIMEOUT)
        {
          log.logTrace("Waiting for messages (No Timeout)", null);
          msg = receiver.receive(timeout);//use timeout to give session access above a chance to detect dead connection
        }
        else
        {
          log.logTrace("Waiting for messages (" + timeout + ")", null);
          msg = receiver.receive(timeout);
        }
      }
      catch (JMSException e)
      {
        log.logInfo("Error reading Queue ", e);
        handleQueueError();
        continue;
      }

      ////////////

       if (msg == null) // timeout
      {
        if (oldTimeout != NO_TIMEOUT) {
            log.logTrace("Timed Out On Queue", null);
            commit = true;

            synchronized (this)
            {
              while ((busy) && (handlersBusy())) 
              {
                try
                {
                  log.logTrace("handlers are busy in run... Waiting...", null);
                  wait(); // wait until all monitors have called us back.
                }
                catch (InterruptedException iioe)
                {
                }
              }
            }

            commit = false;
            commit();
            timeout = NO_TIMEOUT; // wait for a new message on the Queue. No timeouts
        } else {
            timeout = oldTimeout;//looping around again
            log.logTrace("Timed Out On Queue - looping", null);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        // someone has told us to shut down. We just wait until we are told to restart..
        while (!busy)
        {
          log.logInfo("ChangeRequest Reader Suspended", null);
          synchronized (this)
          {
            try
            {
              wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
            }
            log.logInfo("ChangeRequest Reader Activated", null);
            timeout = NO_TIMEOUT; // wait for a new message on the Queue. No timeouts
          }
        }

        change = getChangeRequestFromMessage(msg);
        ..........
}
```

Comment: how exactly is the consumer receiving messages? could you please share a code snippet

Comment: I have added sample code from the JMS consumer, thanks

Comment: your code shows that the thread receiving messages is also processing them. Unless the rest of the code shows otherwise, your application is receiving only one message at a time, and your assumption that the application is prefetching all the 70,000 message is not correct.

Comment: Yes, but when I debug the receiver i can see internally it holds a copy of all the messages inside the Queue. The producers are faster than the consumer. But it seems a Thread calles IMQ_ChannerReader###### is the one in charge of prefetching the messages. The issue is the amount of messages it prefetches.